# Good design for converting a String to different type in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class Data that stores a single piece of data in form of a String, it also stores type to which this data should be converted, the type is stored as an enum constant (to allow only for specyfic types). Data objects that describe one item are stored in DataItem class. Intention is that the Data object corresponds to a field in a table and DataItem represents a full row. It is also important to mention that Data objects are created from DataTemplate class which specifies where to look for this kind of data and its type (so the type of each Data should be known at compile time).

I want this program to be very flexible when it comes to database choice so method "save" comes from Storage interface that allows to use any type of storage (file/RDB/Document database...) after implementing it.

I wonder about a good way of converting those String values from Data objects to the appropriate types so I can save them to database. An easy way would be to use something like this:

```
public void save(DataItem dataItem) {
    for (Data data : dataItem) {
        if (data.getType() == DataType.BOOLEAN) {
            // Convert to String to boolean and save
        }
        else if (data.getType() == DataType.DOUBLE) {
            // Convert to String to double and save
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

But it's not a very good design as I would have to repeat this code for each implemenation of save. It also violates open/closed principle, because if I add some new types I would have to modify all the save methods.

I have also tried using generics or reflection but none of those implementations was satisfactory.

One generic solution that I came up with would require user to to use one of the provided enum constants but then instead of storing enum constant, Data class would store Class instance of corresponding type. That way I stil control what types can be used and get compile time errors if wrong class is picked. This would allow me to implement converter method that works this way.

```
public <T> T convert(Data data, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (data.getType() == Boolean.class) {
        // Convert String to Boolean
        return (T) 
    }
    else if (data.getType() == Double.class) {
            // Convert to String to Double
            return (T)
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I could also use similar pattern and store converting methods in DataType enum alongside allowed data types. Using abstract method that every type would have to specify. Something like:

```
public enum DataType {
    BOOLEAN(Boolean.class){
        @Override
        public <T> T convert(Data data, Class<T> clazz) {
            return clazz.cast(Boolean.parseBoolean(data.getContent()));
        }
    },
    DOUBLE(Double.class){
        @Override
        public <T> T convert(Data data, Class<T> clazz) {
            return clazz.cast(Double.parseDouble(data.getContent()));
        }
    },
    ...;
    ...
    public abstract <T> T convert(Data data, Class<T> clazz);
}
```

In that case I would just have to modify the DataType enum when adding a new type, provided that underlying storage has a method accepting all of the allowed types.

So finally, my questions:
1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. If no, which design should I choose?

Comment: You can use **Integer.toString**, **Double.toString**, etc

Comment: Why can't you use Java's strong type system to begin with? Where is your data coming from? Or are you implementing an object-relational mapper of some sort?

Comment: @0ddlyoko toString methods convert other type to String I want to convert String to some other type

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic My data comes from various text files and web scraping.

Comment: Your code will always violate the open/closed principle because "_the type is stored as an enum constant_" and you cannot extend an `Enum` to add additional types.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I know that that's why I wrote "I have also tried using generics or reflection but none of those implementations was satisfactory.", and I'm trying to find a better solution

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic I guess that it can be considered as an object-relational mapper. But how Java's type system can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your conversion functions in a `Map<Class<?>,Function<String,?>>` map.  Look up the conversion function based on the `Class`.  Add new functions to the map as new types are created.

```
Map<Class<?>,Function<String,?>> map = new HashMap<>();

<T> T convert(String data, Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) map.get(clazz).apply(data);
}
```

Alternately, you can create your own `DataType` class, and create **singleton** instances for each type, and add appropriate conversion methods to each singleton:

```
public abstract class DataType<T> {
    <T> T fromString(String data);
}

public final static DataType<Boolean> BOOLEAN = new DataType<Boolean>() {
    Boolean fromString(String data) {
        ...
    }
};

// ...

Data data = ...
Object value = data.getType().fromString(data.getContent())
```

You can add additional fields and methods to `DataType`, as appropriate.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, getType() method would return one of implemented DataType<T> singleton instances? If that's the case should I expect user to pick one of those instances from some sort of collection as a form of specifying the type for Data instead of providing an instance of Class<T>?

Comment: Yes, just like you would have had to pick one of the instances of the `DataType` enum when you used `if (data.getType() == DataType.BOOLEAN)`.  They need not be stored in a collection, although they could be.  (If you have a 1-to-1 mapping between `Class<?>` and `DataType`, then `Data` could just store the class.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Interface (Savable) that each of your savable classes would need to implement with 2 interface functions called toSaveString and initFromSaveString.

Then when load from the DB you would just need switch statement to determine which class to load the data to.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't explain this clearly, Data objects purpose is to store data so it can be segregated into DataItems before saving to database, it will get input from other resources.